# How to make Safari open new tab as google.com

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser

I have just started using Safari. In Google Chrome I can assign which the new tab opens. I am not sure how to make Safari open new tab as "google.com" when I click the "+" button on Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari Preferences > General

New tabs open with… Homepage.  New windows is optional.
Then set Google as your homepage.
If you go to your normal Google default search page first, then use Set to Current Page, the URL will be better-specified than just typing 'google.com' in the address box.

[image]